# Data Dictionary Storage and Retrieval with MongoDB and Node.js Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, reporting, data-dictionary

I have the following requirement in my project.

It is a reporting application so mainly will be storing data about my entities once and most of the times will be retrieving it and showing them on the webpage as different reports. I am using node.js and mongodb for this project.

The data is in the form of excel. There are more than 2000 columns and each column has one short code like s0a_1, s0a_2, s1a_1, s1a_2 etc. Each column code is mapped to a long meaningful text. For example, s01_1 -> What is the name of the person ? , s01_2 -> 'Project Name' etc. And for each column there will be a corresponding value which is a number most of the time.

In my reports, I need to show long meaningful text and corresponding value.

So, what is the best way to achieve this ?

We can think of the following ways:

1. Create a collection in mongo and store shortcode/text as key value pair and each time I replace short code with text before sending response to the client.
2. Store in a property file as key value pair
3. Use redis for this specific purpose

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.